# Person who organizes and presents at school functions

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to put my previous activities on some form for High School and need to find an accurate word to describe what I did.

- I participated in event organization in school (helped planning the event, added several things here and there)
- I spoke at all school events(prom, grad bash, graduation, beginning of school year speech)
- I was basically the man saying: "Ladies and Gentlemen, today we are proud to welcome you on our XXX event bla-bla-bla", "Now we ask you to welcome our dear Principal Mr. XYZ". Then when that Principal ended his speech I announced other people and in the end I said "Thanks everyone for coming/something similar" and fancy music started playing and event was pretty much over.

Ideas are following:

- "Master of ceremonies" and
- "Anchorman".

I consider my English level enough for everything I need but ask your help to not miss this **very** specific word.

Sample sentence: "He was XXXX at this school in 2016-2017."

Comment: 'Master of ceremonies" would seem to fit very well. Why would you not use that?

Comment: I would suggest "organizer and master of ceremonies".

Comment: @HotLicks thanks, that what I would use. I'm new to StackExchange, how can I mark your comment as an appropriate answer?

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. I've helped edit your question for clarity. It's a good first question! You might want to add why you weren't quite satisfied with the two ideas you presented. // Stack Exchange sites treat 'answers' and 'comments' quite differently. Only answers can be marked as accepted (e.g. that by [MattBecker82](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/430063/142322)) - you do that by clicking the 'tick'/'check mark' next to the answer. Comments are for clarification or other communication, and don't have much formal status in the system, though you can up-vote useful ones.

Comment: If you particularly like a suggestion someone commented about, you can ask whether they'd mind turning their comment into an answer so you can accept it. There are certain standards for answers on Stack Exchange, notably that answers need to be justified so that they are in some sense 'objectively correct', and it's up to the individual whether they're willing to post a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

In British English the word **compère** means someone who introduces others during a variety show etc. However, the word suggests a role within a particular show, rather than an ongoing responsibility.

[Definition of compère](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/compere)

Answer (score 2):

Front Man.

In UK English it sounds odd to be ‘Master of Ceremonies’ for a school. That role is normally associated with an event or series of events, it is not usually a role at a achool.

You could say you were ‘event organiser and MC for a series of fundraising and other school events’ or ‘for all school events’ if that is so.

How about ‘front man’ - this broader term carries the sense that you might do more than MC - for example you might be interviewed in the media etc.

Again it is associated with ‘events’ but you can then say ‘I was front man for the school for x, y, and z events, and was also involved in organising them.’

Or you could say ‘I was front man for *all school social activities*’ or whatever.

Front man carries the sense that you *represent* the school, publicly - and perhaps carries more gravitas than MC.

Answer (score 0):

Master of ceremonies is technically the correct term but sounds overly formal and even a bit pompous. In practice people use the word emcee which is just a play on the abbreviation for master of ceremonies, M.C.

In terms of most formal to least formal the list goes:

Master of ceremonies

Emcee

M.C.

In my experience master of ceremonies is used for very formal events, emcee for everyday events like school and workplace presentations and M.C. during informal occasions like parties and dances.